# How to pass an object to Angular component attribute/binding

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular 1.5+ component, I can't seem to pass an object to the component's attribute/binding when that object's key references a variable.

```
//inside parent ctrl
vm.dog = 'hey'
<my-component field="{cat: vm.dog}"></my-component>

//my-component
controller: 'MyComponentCtrl as vm',
bindings: {field: '<'}
```

In my-component's ctrl, the object is showing up on scope but as:

```
{cat: undefined}
```

Any ideas?? I also tried doing:

```
<my-component field="{cat: '+vm.dog+'}"></my-component>
```

and

```
<my-component field="{cat: {{vm.dog}}}"></my-component>
```

Comment: What is your parent controller named? It should be wrapped in something like <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as vm"><my-component></my-component></div>

Comment: try to  `bindings: {field: '='}`

Comment: It should work. `undefined` means that `vm.dog` is not accessible in your template. But you are not giving enough details to answer why.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/X279OTIEmBB0xhMG0IK9?p=preview. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the plnkr. That helped me determine controllerAs is the issue. I'm using the controllerAs on the component definition, and when I tried that on your example, it broke. Not sure of a way around that. I tried `controller: 'childCtrl as vm` and `controller: 'childCtrl', controllerAs: 'vm'`

Comment: Still works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mWVLDxRXZ3JzUKCOPx2k?p=preview. Again, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.